# How do I code cover 100% parent component function called from child component in react using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function in my parent component which is being called on button click from a child component. In my child component, I am able to simulate the button click but separately the function is not getting code covered from the parent component test file. How do I code coverage the function in parent component test file using jest and enzyme?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ParentComponent = ({ param1, param2 }) => {




const fnToBeCalledFromChildComponent = (event, param2) => {
   doSomething;
  };
    return (
      <div id="customcomponent">
                     <ChildComponent
              fnToBeCalledFromChildComponent={fnToBeCalledFromChildComponent}
               />
             </div>
);
};

ParentComponent.propTypes = {
    Param1: PropTypes.bool,
    Param2: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object),
  };
export default withRouter(ParentComponent);



import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const ChildComponent = ({
                           fnToBeCalledFromChildComponent,
                         }) => (
                   

    <div id=“mainDiv”>
                                    <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-6">
                                     <Button
                                       id="btn1”
                                       onClick={(event) => fnToBeCalledFromChildComponent(event, param2)}
                                     >Btn
                                     </Button>
                                   </div>
                                 </div>
                           </div>
);
ChildComponent.propTypes = {
  fnToBeCalledFromChildComponent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
export default withRouter(ChildComponent);
```

Comment: You can try it by render the parent component in test file using enzyme mount. Then find the child component button and simulate the event. At the end validate the expected output of the click. It will increase the coverage. Or for the better understanding you can update the question with the code snippet that you  are trying.

Comment: When I try to simulate the child component button click in my parent component test file, it is not able to find the button.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: @AnkitKatheriya Any help on this?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your test code?